# How to get attribute from a interfce instance from struct in Go

Tags: go, go-interface

I want to get the **v.val**, but the go compiler throw me an Error:

> v.val undefined (type testInterface has no field or method val)

but in the **v.testMe** method,It work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testInterface interface {
    testMe()
}

type oriValue struct {
    val int
}

func (o oriValue) testMe() {
    fmt.Println(o.val, "I'm test interface")
}

func main() {
    var v testInterface = &oriValue{
        val: 1,
    }
    //It work!
    //print 1 "I'm test interface"
    v.testMe()
    //error:v.val undefined (type testInterface has no field or method val)
    fmt.Println(v.val)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert back your interface to the real type. Please check below :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testInterface interface {
    testMe()
}

type oriValue struct {
    val int
}

func (o oriValue) testMe() {
    fmt.Println(o.val, "I'm test interface")
}

func main() {
    var v testInterface = &oriValue{
        val: 1,
    }
    //It work!
    //print 1 "I'm test interface"
    v.testMe()
    //error:v.val undefined (type testInterface has no field or method val)
    fmt.Println(v.(*oriValue).val)
}
```

Check on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FBruPDiKJZ)

Comment: Thanks a lot!That's save my day!